# Not able to install requests for python3.3 in linux

Tags: python, linux, python-requests

```
sudo -u <username>/lm/tools/extern/python/libs/lmdata33-env/bin/pip-3.3 install requests
Downloading/unpacking requests
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement requests
No distributions at all found for requests
Storing complete log in /home/lmbuild1/.pip/pip.log
```

Additional info: Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an older version of pip that attempts to connect to PyPI over plain HTTP.  This is insecure and has always been insecure, and as a result [PyPI started disallowing plain HTTP requests a week ago](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2017-October/031712.html).  You need to upgrade your version of pip to fix this.  If your OS's package manager does not provide a more recent version of pip, you can follow [these instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py) instead by downloading https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and running `python get-pip.py`.